# Trouble with GeoPackage - is SpatiaLite a solid alternative?

Tags: qgis, spatialite, geopackage

I like GeoPackage because it is very versatile, small and compact and works well with QGIS. But the more I use GeoPackage and recommend it to my customers, the more negative experiences I have: especially data loss! I can't reproduce it, but my customers tell me that geometry or tables are lost or damaged while editing. Sometimes the tables still exist, but there are no entries (but the number of rows) and they cannot be deleted. I cannot repair or reproduce the problem.

Does anyone else have such experience with GeoPackage in QGIS and what could be a good alternative? SpatiaLite?

EDIT: the GeoPackage is not stored in the network or the cloud, nor is used/edit by many people at the same time, but what all GeoPackages have in common are virtual fields!

Comment: Without knowing what causes that data loss it is hard to recommend an alternative because it will probably happen just the same. Better find the root cause instead of trying to change minute details on the other end of the issue.

Comment: SpatiaLite and GeoPackage are both SQLite databases and they have rather similar concepts. Are your customers trying to use GeoPackage as multi-user database so that many users are editing the same database?

Comment: And are your users trying to edit data stored on a network drive?